# If statement reversibly executing instructions in node js with express and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, if-statement, mongoose

Whenever I tried to execute the code it's not going inside the if statement despite the value of `listName` is exactly matching with the if condition. `List.findOne()` is also returning null everytime.

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;
  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });
  console.log(listName);
  if (listName === 'Today') {
    console.log("Entered");
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({
        name : listName
      }, function(err,foundList){
          console.log(foundList);
          foundList.items.push(item);
          foundList.save();
          res.redirect("/" + listName);
      });
    }
});
```

You can check what is actually being returned by terminal:

```
Server started on port 3000
Today 
null
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: it clearly means you `foundList` is `null`. there is no record found for `listName` in your `List` collection.

Comment: ```const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemSchema],
};```

Comment: and created a new item

Comment: ```const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });```

Comment: What exactly is "list" on your HTML any way?

Comment: Also, can you put brackets or quotes around console.log(listName) to make sure you don't have trailing spaces or such?

Comment: ```{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb660da3b419024aceb4b97"), "name" : "Home", "items" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb660d43b419024aceb4b90"), "name" : "Welcome to your todolist!" 
}, { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb660d43b419024aceb4b91"), "name" : "Hit the + button to 
add a new list." }, { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb660d43b419024aceb4b92"), "name" : "<-- hit this to delete an item." } ], "__v" : 0 }```                                                                 when I triggered localhost:3000/Home route, database gets created as you can see, it's not empty

Comment: ```<form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %> ">+</button>
      </form>```

Comment: got it folks,thanks for getting involved.<button type="submit" name="list" **value="<%= listTitle %> ">**+</button>   The problem was here, unknowingly space got added here.

Comment: So I was kinda right. Hah.

Comment: Indeed! @KaseyChang